# How to get LitElement or LitHtml to render Templates from String

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

Here's a thing I have some issues to do. I have a field component that can implement different types of widgets.

I have a typical view that looks like this:

```
<form model="model" record_id="record_id">
  <field name="title" />
  <field name="body" widget="text"/>
</form>
```

When the form is loaded, it checks for a View Description for fields, so the spec of the fields is obtained indirectly but can be passed manually to the field to override the field spec..

In this case, the spec looks a bit like this:

```
{
  title: {
    type: 'string',
    widget: 'char'
  },
  body: {
    type: 'string',
    widget: 'text',
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is this a field widget that can dynamically load a custom webcomponent as a child.

I tried with this:

```
render () {
    return html`
      <${this.widget} @change=${update_value}></${this.widget}>
    `
}
```

And with this:

```
render () {
    return html`
      <div is=${this.widget} @change=${update_value}></div>
    `
}
```

But the only thing that seamingly work is this:

```
render () {
    this.innerHTML = `<${this.widget}></${this.widget}>`
    return html`<div><slot></slot></div>`
}
```

The downside of this is that I cannot automatically bind onChange event to the child as it's the widget that will bindItself to its parentField. Ideally I'd want to be able to use the widget directly that would allow the Field component to map directly to a selected set of events that widget can fire instead of hoping that the widget will correctly register itself to the field...

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`<${this.widget} @change=${update_value}></${this.widget}>` would be really nice, but unfortunately it will not work until static directive will lands in lit-html (https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/78)

You can try to use [unsafeHTML directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml) like this:

```
const html = unsafeHTML`
  <${this.widget} @change=${update_value}></${this.widget}>
`;
```

but I am worried it is not sufficient in your case, because with this directive you're no longer constructing a lit template, but just a plain string. There will be no efficient re-rendering.

Note also that, you should use this directive only if you can trust the source that your data comes from, as it may lead to XSS vulnerabilities.